# 'GTMSessionFetcherService.h' file not found

Tags: ios, gmail-api, xcode7

I am working with Gmail API in **iOS** on Xcode 7 beta. When I compiled using Xcode 6.4 the program given in **Gmail API** documentation, it worked perfectly but in Xcode 7 beta I am getting the GTMSessionFetcherService.h not found.

I wanted to work on Xcode & beta so please do suggest a method avoid the above error